# Как можно получить урл страницы в UMI CMS

Tags: php, umi

Здравствуйте.
Есть id объекта. Как можно получить урл страницы в UMI CMS, используя только object_id ?

Пробовал сделать как то [так](http://wiki.umisoft.ru/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%83_%D1%81_%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC_%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0_object_id), но не получилось.

Answer (score 2):

Приведенный пример будет работать, если объект установлен в качестве источника данных для элемента (страница).

Не у всех объектов могут быть страницы (используются качестве источника данных элементом), например наименование справочника тоже 
объект, но страницы для него не создаются.